# Why position sticky content is disappearing when i give z-index

Tags: html, css

i have problem with position `sticky and z-index`  whenever i apply `z-index` to positioned `sticky` element its content is disappearing

**Question:** i want to use `z-index` for positioned `sticky` element without any comprise(simple way)

**below is my problem:**

```css
.sticky,.no-sticky{
  width:250px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.sticky input{
   position: sticky;  
   z-index: 23;
}

.icon:before{
    content: "...";
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 31px;
    top: -16px;
    right: 84px;
}

/* ====== run ===================2 */

.sticky1,.no-sticky1{
  width:250px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.sticky1 input{
   position: sticky;  
   /*z-index: 23;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="no-sticky">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="icon"></span>
</div>

<hr>

<p>see below input ... dots are not appearing </p>

<div class="sticky">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="icon"></span>
</div>


<h1>Run without z-index</h1>

<div class="no-sticky1">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="icon"></span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="sticky1">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

**Problem Showing:**

```css
#container{
  width:175px;
  height: 200px;
/*   background:#ccc; */
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index:40px;
}

input{
   position: sticky;  
   /*z-index: 23; */
   top:0;
   left:0;
  border:none;
  outline: 1px solid #cccccc52;
}

.icon:before{
  content:"...";
  position: absolute;
  font-size:30px;
  top:-16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span style="position:relative;">
      <input type="text">
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </span>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p>lorem</p>
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: that's because the input gets a higher z-index, therefore it goes over the `:before`

Comment: how to solve this @ZohirSalak ?

Comment: Well, What is the intended behavior from all this ? Also you might wanna look into placeholders

Comment: note that the use of sticky here is useless since the sticky element is defining the height of his parent

Comment: what browser are you using? i see dots in firefox but not chrome

Answer (score 0):

### OPTION ONE

```
  .sticky input{
     position: sticky;  
     z-index: -1;
  }
```

Make the z index of the input -1 so that it's behind the dots.

### OPTION TWO

```
  .icon:before{
      content: "...";
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 31px;
      top: -16px;
      right: 84px;
      z-index: 1;
  }
```

Make the z-index of the icon higher than 0.

Either way you just gotta make sure that you are applying the higher z-index to the thing you want in front.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* how can a class be clasified as sticky and relative at the same time ?????? its eigther sticky or not, you cant use X index and using like 3 diferent positions for it*/
.sticky {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}

.icon2:after{
    content: "...";
    font-size: 31px;
}
.no-sticky {
height: 1000px;
}
/* when you stick something you need to tell the position of that item, you did everthing backwards, also you need to add a lenght to the height to be able to scroll the sticky part of it, otherwise is not going to move*/
```

```html
<div class="sticky">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="icon2"></span>
</div>
<div class="no-sticky">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="icon"></span>
</div>

<hr>

<p>see below input ... dots are not appearing </p>
```

Heres how you do that.
Remember that your moving your whole class, not just icon.